# Serving the frontend contents with Spring Boot and Tomcat

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, web-frontend

I'm going to create a very typical and not resource-demanding frontend+backend project, and my general question is how to organize it in a better way.

The backend part provides a REST API and here Java and Spring Boot will be utilized. The question about having embedded Tomcat or deploying a WAR is still open. I would prefer to deploy a WAR, unless another option has some advantages for my case. For the development I use Eclipse and Maven, and eventually all this will work on RHEL.

The frontend part is a web-application implementing a UI that accesses the API. Here I'm going to use React.

The number of tutorials suggest to utilize *frontend-maven-plugin* for serving the frontend content by the means of Spring Boot (using *node* and *npm* under the hood). This looks nice and compact. As a result we have a web-app at:

```
http://my.domain:8080/index.html
```

accessing the API at:

```
http://my.domain:8080/api/...
```

But no one of those I have found so far suggests to run the web-app at the default http port (80) at:

```
http://my.domain/index.html
```

which I consider as a must for real production.

There are also ways to redirect calls from port 80 to 8080, but doesn't this look like a tricky patch?
Apache Tomcat itself can be (apparently) configured to run on port 80, but this does not look nice for me as well.

So, is there a way to organize such a project as a whole one (preferably managed by Spring Boot and Tomcat) and not having its parts "scattered" around in different independent services?

Comment: You don’t want to run a production app on the internet without a real web server proxy like nginx, httpd or haproxy.

Comment: @Strelok Is it a general practice to proxify calls through (for example) Apache WebService to the frontend that is actually served by Apache Tomcat?

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'webapp' folder and this configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {


@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations("/");
}

@Override
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("/index.html");
    }
}
```