# 404 Page while running Spring and angular in same port

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot

I created Spring boot + angular 8 application which was running succesfully in two different port like 8080 and 4200 without any issues. Then I decided to run the application in same port (8080). I ran `ng build --prod` and got the dist folder. Moved that Dist folder into the spring application and the folder looked like this image

[image: Spring boot application with Angular Dist folder]

The corresponding pom.xml is as follows

```
  <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                  <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/target/classes/static/</outputDirectory >
                  <resources>
                      <resource>
                          <directory>${project.build.directory}/fleetManagement/dist/fleetManagement</directory >
                      </resource>
                  </resources>
                <nonFilteredFileExtensions>
                    <nonFilteredFileExtension>woff</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                    <nonFilteredFileExtension>ttf</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                    <nonFilteredFileExtension>woff2</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                    <nonFilteredFileExtension>eot</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                    <nonFilteredFileExtension>swf</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                    <nonFilteredFileExtension>ico</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                    <nonFilteredFileExtension>png</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                    <nonFilteredFileExtension>svg</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                    <nonFilteredFileExtension>jpg</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                    <nonFilteredFileExtension>jpeg</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                </nonFilteredFileExtensions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

When I ran the aplication and hit http://localhost:8080 - it goes to HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
but the api's are still running , like http://localhost:8080/api/vehicles - provide json data from backend

My application.properties file as follows,

```
server.servlet.context-path=/api
server.port=8080
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55848395/serving-the-frontend-contents-with-spring-boot-and-tomcat this might be related to your question.

Comment: do you have the properties `server.servlet.context-path=???` in your application.properties ?

Comment: Possible replica of the same
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53058824/angular-and-spring-boot-are-not-binding-together-so-they-run-on-same-port-8080

Comment: @RUAROThibault, yeah , I have

Answer (score 0):

## What is happening

When deploying your application and copying your ressources inside the `src/main/ressources` folder, you then expect Spring to render the front app for you. But Spring is a server, and as a server, it serves you given the configuration you gave him.

By using `server.servlet.context-path=/api`, you tell Spring : Everything will be prefixed by "/api"... Therefor, if you try requesting : `http://localhost:8080/`, Spring will tell you it knows nothing about such a URL, because for him, everything is supposed to be prefixed by `/api`...

So naturally, you would say : Then, let's access `http://localhost:8080/api`. But it is not that easy... I don't know yet exactly what is going on, but I guess you have index.html file inside your `src/main/resources` or `src/main/resources/public`... and when you try to access `http://localhost:8080/api` it will try to lookup for a file index.html inside `src/main/resources/{public}/api/index.html`... And it doesn't find any. Hence the exception.

## Temporary solution

I've faced a similar issue with VueJS and Spring Boot. Without loosing too much time, my solution was to remove the properties `server.servlet.context-path=/api` and manually prefixing my controller with the annotation `@RequestMapping`.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class MyController {
    ...
}
```

It should do the trick, but I am not a big fan.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but the solution doesn't work. :(